# Deleting gaps does not move clips in other tracks?

Tags: davinci-resolve

I'm quite new to DaVinci Resolve, so bear with me please. I'm having an issue with deleting gaps in the timeline and ripple deleting.

I have a clip in Track 1 that I want to delete, and then remove the gap created by that deletion. The complication comes because further on in the video I have some clips in Track 2 that are overlayed on the clips from Track 1.

Whenever I delete the gap created by deleting the clip, the clips in Track 2 are not moving, causing the overlay to appear at the wrong point in the video. This is very frustrating as it pulls pretty much my entire video out of sync. I appreciate any help.

Here is a link to a video showing exactly what I mean: https://vimeo.com/841960350?share=copy